# Finding Post doc position during last year of PhD

Tags: postdocs

I reached to last year of my PhD in mechanical/material entineering in europe. I am not satisfied about my situation. Not good institute, not good recommendation, and not many articles. Thus, I want to really spend my last year to grasp whatever I need for future work. I am 31 years old. Do you think another Phd could be a solution (i know about yhe complexity of procees)? What can I do in last year?
Rrcently I added machine learning to my work but I am in doubt everytime whethet it is for me or not since there are some papers under review with my friend and maybe I could go deep. Any idea?
sometimes I think that maybe with some programming knowledge i can get a job if post doc or another phd is not possible. Thetefore, some coursera certificate I achieved. I am lost

Comment: Please search this site. No, another PhD is not a solution. Yes, it is scary to proceed to the next stage of your career but everyone has to go through this.

Answer (score 0):

I felt in your situation so many times.

I would say what worked for me, start looking at the requirements and skills of positions that attract you (the earlier the better), even post-docs. The more you search, the more you will find one that actually requires the skills you ALREADY HAVE. Take your time to build your CV and application for those ones. It will be ok, just apply, and do not get dissappointed with rejections.